# Как расставить запятые правильно

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение: ...о продаже посредством публичного предложения одноэтажного нежилого здания площадью 40,4 кв.м, с прилегающим земельным участком площадью 161 кв.м, находящегося по адресу:
Нужна ли запятая перед "с прилегающим" и нужно ли выделить запятыми с обеих сторон "площадью 40,4 кв.м"Спасибо, если поможете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы от чьей-то трактовки проставленных запятых не возникало ложного понимания входимости одной площади в другую (например, "с участком - столько-то"), я бы заключил в скобки оба упоминания о площадях (без запятой между "домом" и "участком"):

... нежилого здания (площадь 40,4 кв.м) с прилегающим к нему земельным участком (площадь 161 кв.м), ...